# How can find balance using linq query

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to write a query of my bank balance. Which I can do in SQL query. I can't figure out how to do this using Linq Query. It would be helpful if any experienced person could help me.

```cs
public class tbl_BankName
{
    [Key]
    public int bankid { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
}

public class tbl_bankTransaction
{
    [Key]
    public int bankTransctionid { get; set; }
    public int bankid { get; set; }
    public decimal? debited { get; set; }
    public decimal? credited { get; set; }
}

public class bankvm
{
    public int bankid { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
    public decimal? debited { get; set; }
    public decimal? credited { get; set; }
    public decimal? balance { get; set; }
}
```

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
    b.bankid, c.BankName, c.AccountNo, b.Balance
FROM
    (SELECT
         a.bankid, 
         Balance = SUM(ISNULL(a.credited, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(a.debited, 0))
     FROM 
         tbl_BankTransactions a
     GROUP BY
         a.bankid 
     HAVING
         SUM(ISNULL(a.credited, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(a.debited, 0)) <> 0) b
JOIN
    tbl_BankNames c ON c.bankid = b.bankid
WHERE
    b.bankid = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var context = new DbContext();
var query = from transaction in context.tbl_bankTransaction
            join bank in context.tbl_BankName on transaction.bankid equals bank.bankid
            group transaction by new { transaction.bankid, bank.BankName, bank.AccountNo } into g
            let totalCredited = g.Sum(x => x.credited ?? 0)
            let totalDebited = g.Sum(x => x.debited ?? 0)
            let balance = totalCredited - totalDebited
            where g.Key.bankid == 2 && balance != 0
            select new bankvm
            {
                bankid = g.Key.bankid,
                BankName = g.Key.BankName,
                AccountNo = g.Key.AccountNo,
                balance = balance
            };

var result = query.ToList();
```

I Hope This works if any error please let me know will try to fix Thanks you

Comment: Thanks for the help. But when I omit the balance part, the quarry works correctly. Otherwise giving error.

Comment: @Jewelserniabad It your problem resolved or still exists? after omitting if yes please mark it answers else tell me the issue will work on it...

Comment: let balance not work, its get me error-
Suryateja KONDLA

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdZTR.png
Thanks for the help. But when I omit the balance part, the quarry works correctly. Otherwise giving error. 

var query = from transaction in _context.tbl_BankTransactions
join bank in _context.tbl_BankNames on transaction.bankid equals bank.bankid
group transaction by new { transaction.bankid, bank.BankName,bank.AccountNo } into g 
//let totalCredited = g.Sum(x => x.credited ?? 0)  
//let totalDebited = g.Sum(x => x.debited ?? 0)
//let balance = totalCredited - totalDebited   
//where g.Key.bankid == 2 && balance != 0 select new bankvm
{bankid = g.Key.bankid,
BankName = g.Key.BankName,
AccountNo = g.Key.AccountNo,
//blance = balance};
var list = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).